# Почему в googleMap нет onTouchListener?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api, google-maps

Почему в googleMap нет onTouchListener?

Мне нужно прослушивать событие когда человек перестает перетаскивать камеру. Думал сделать прослушку UP. но у гугла нет TouchListener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPD:

Можно на карту (GoogleMap) повесить слушатель начала и окончания скрола юзером. Методы `setOnStartCameraMovingListener` и `setOnCameraIdleListener`

---

**Старый способ**

Судя по [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13728006/3212712) вам может помочь переопределение `MapFragment` с целью оборачивания его в контейнер, коий будет отслеживать когда юзер двигает карту пальцем и когда перестаёт:

---

Класс-обёртка для отлова событий опускания/убирания пальца

```
private class TouchableWrapper extends FrameLayout {
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mMapIsTouched = true;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mMapIsTouched = false;
                break;
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Изменения в переопределённом `MapFragment`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mOriginalContentView = super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, 
            savedInstanceState);

    mTouchView = new TouchableWrapper(getActivity());
    mTouchView.addView(mOriginalContentView);

    return mTouchView;
}

@Override
public View getView() {
    return mOriginalContentView;
}
```

Далее в слушателе изменения камеры проверяем наш флаг:

```
private final OnCameraChangeListener mOnCameraChangeListener = 
        new OnCameraChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
        if (!mMapIsTouched) {
            refreshClustering(false);
        }
    }
};
```

---

В комментах на en-SO пишут, что это может не всегда работать из-за асинхронности вызова слушателя апдейта камеры

Comment: Если это не самый лучший вариант. То как мне быть тогда? Как проффесионалы справляются с такой ситуацией. Когда маркеров на карте миллионы и все сразу грузить и отображать не вариант, так как начнет все тормозить.

Поэтому при запросе на сервер я получаю по 10 маркеров от тек. положения. Так вот в каких моментах мне делать запрос на сервер?

Comment: @xTIGRx, ну, возможно тогда onCameraUpdate и не нужен и можно просто в событии отпускания пальца стартовать таймер с нужной задержкой, по истечении которой стартовать запрос в сеть. А в момент DOWN собтия таймер отменять.